# identifying patterns from string and updating the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I have a list with a specific pattern and I want to create and update a dataframe based on that format.
Below is the list:

```
text =  ['chocolate1','a;b;','c;d','icecream','e;f;','g;h', 'i;j', 'cookie', 'k;l', 'm;n']
```

If you carefully observe the pattern is:

I want to extract each chocolate name and add it to chocolate number column.
The final dataframe would look something like below:

```
|chocolate#|chocolateName|
|chocolate1|a|
|chocolate1|b|
|chocolate1|c|
|chocolate1|d|
|icecream|e|
|icecream|f|
|icecream|g|
|icecream|h|
|icecream|i|
|icecream|j|
|cookie|k|
|cookie|l|
|cookie|m|
|cookie|n|
```

Based on the data I have, I am trying few things. Nothing seems to be working.

```
new_text = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    if len(line.split())==0 or len(line.split())==1:
      continue
    else:
      new_text.append(line)
for i in new_text[13:]:
  if ';' not in i:
    title_index = new_text.index(i)
    print(title_index)
    break
```

Comment: Where is your input `df`? Could you include this.

Comment: I dont have a `df`, I need to create one by processing the string elements in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a pandas dataframe from list
text =  ['chocolate1','a;b;','c;d','icecream','e;f;','g;h', 'i;j', 'cookie', 'k;l', 'm;n']
s = pd.Series(text)
df = s.to_frame(name='letters')

# Create new column food where strings do not have ;
df['food'] = df.loc[~df['letters'].str.contains(';'), 'letters']
df['food'] = df['food'].ffill()

# remove rows that doesn't have ';' for letters
df = df[df['letters'].str.contains(';')].copy()

# Explode letters into rows of dataframe
df['letters'] = df['letters'].str.split(';')
df_out = df.explode('letters')

# Eliminate rows with blank for letters
df_out = df_out[df_out['letters'] != '']

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  letters        food
1       a  chocolate1
1       b  chocolate1
2       c  chocolate1
2       d  chocolate1
4       e    icecream
4       f    icecream
5       g    icecream
5       h    icecream
6       i    icecream
6       j    icecream
8       k      cookie
8       l      cookie
9       m      cookie
9       n      cookie
```